# How to Supress "Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable."

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I got warning from bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247). How to supress it?

```
$ google-chrome-stable --headless --single-process --disable-audio-output --dump-dom https://domains.google.com/checkip
[1224/012030.647481:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
<html><head></head><body>35.229.216.43</body></html>
```

I expected no "Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable." warning without `--log-level`.

Comment: I got the same error, did you resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Here is [a new headless](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/) since Chrome 112

**Try out the new Headless**

To try the new Headless mode, pass the --headless=new command-line flag:

```
$ chrome --headless=new
```

Also you in new Chrome can get error "*No accept header receieved on handshake response*", then try:

```
$ chrome --headless=new --remote-allow-origins=*
```

Comment: Thanks, your proposal solved my issues when starting chrome!