# Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable

Tags: linux, debugging, debian, chromium, headless-browser

I am encountering an error message while running a command that involves launching Chromium in headless mode with various options. The specific command I am using is as follows:

```
chromium --incognito --headless --remote-allow-origins=* --remote-debugging-port=7717 --disable-web-security --no-sandbox --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --disable-gpu --ignore-certificate-errors --alsa-output-device=alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-stereo https://<ip-address>:5000/?HAWK_01
```

However, when executing this command, I receive the following error message:

```
Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
```

I'm not familiar with the term "Floss manager" and why it's necessary for my command. I've searched extensively but haven't found any relevant information or solutions related to this error.

Could someone please shed some light on what the "Floss manager" is and why it's causing this error? Additionally, any guidance on how to resolve or work around this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm running this command on a Debian docker container (specifically, bullseye). I have already tried reinstalling Chromium and ensuring that all dependencies are up to date, but the error persists.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting the `--headless` flag to `new` (`--headless=new`) as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905110/how-to-supress-floss-manager-not-present-cannot-set-floss-enable-disable)? Solved the issue for me.